# anticipate orders

Tags: phrases

In "The Oracle of the Dog" by G. K. Chesterton, Father Brown was talking about a former officer who **left the Indian police through breaking some red-tape regulations** and taking some sort of risk and responsibility of his own.

“This man was a gambler,” said the priest, “and a man in disgrace for having taken risks and **anticipated orders**. It was probably for something pretty unscrupulous, for every imperial police is more like a Russian secret police than we like to think. But he had gone beyond the line and failed."

Does "anticipate" here mean "obey" as mentioned in this dictionary 
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/anticipate?

If so, how he obeyed the orders and broke the rules at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Anticipate" does not mean obey.**

The definition you are presumably looking at is:

> to answer (a question), obey (a command), or satisfy (a request) **before it is made**

I have emphasized the important part of the definition, which is "before it is made". You only **anticipate** an order if you do it before the order is given.

While it can theoretically be OK to anticipate an order, in this case it probably means he did something like arresting someone before he was ordered to. He was gambling that the order would be given, but if it wasn't it means he did it without orders, which would be illegal.